# Icon Image Keeps Repeating in Background

Tags: html, css, phpbb

**CSS**

This icon image in on my recently installed forums style keeps repeating, creating an obnoxious background that is too noisy and distracts from the actual words.

Here is a copy of that particular element's CSS:

```
element {
}
ul.topiclist li.row dl {
    padding: 2px 0;
}
ul.topiclist dl {
    font-size: 10px;
}
ul.topiclist dl {
    position: relative;
}
.clearfix, fieldset dl, ul.topiclist dl, dl.polls {
    overflow: hidden;
}
dl.icon {
    background-position: 95% 15%;
    position: relative;
}
.topic_read_mine {
    background-image: url("./images/icons/topic_read_mine.png");
}
```

I was able to retrieve this from the browser inspection tool @ http://www.gaymerscommunity.com/viewforum.php?f=4

I would like for the icon to display only once. It is meant to be an indicator if the forum was read/unread.

**Answered Below**

added 'background-repeat: no-repeat' to the ul.topiclist dl
Also found 'dl.icon' and adjusted the background-position to display on the right.

Thank you.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific *problem* or *error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `.topic_read` needs `background-repeat: no-repeat`. In the future your question should include the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css Code to fix that.

```
ul.topiclist dl {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

There is no PHP in here